# Problema con Image Intervention Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, imagen

estoy tratando de integrar Image Intervention en mi codigo para poder hacerles un resize a la imagen pero no logro hacerlo funcionar.

El error que arroja es el siguiente:

Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::make() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\wamp64\www\proyecto-laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php on line 1570

y el codigo del controllador Image es este:

```
public function save(Request $request){

    //Validacion
    $validate = $this->validate($request, [
        'description' => 'required',
        'image_path' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg'
    ]);

    //Recoger datos
    $image_path = $request->file('image_path');
    $description = $request->input('description');

    //Asignar valores al objeto
    $user = \Auth::user();
    $image = New Image();
    $image->user_id = $user->id; 
    $image->description = $description;

    //Subir fichero
    if($image_path){
        $image_path_name = time().$image_path->getClientOriginalName();
        Storage::disk('images')->put($image_path_name, File::get($image_path));
        $image->image_path = $image_path_name;
    }

    //Resize y Subir a la BD
    Image::make($image_path)->resize(400,400)->save($image);

    //Redirect
    return redirect()->route('home')->with([
        'message' => 'La imagen se a cargado correctamente'
    ]);
}
```

---

Muchas gracias por responder, te cuento que me sigue dando el mismo error.
Te muestro todo el codigo incluido los Facade que estoy utilizando.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use App\Image;
use App\Comment;
use App\Like;
use Intervention\Image\ImageManager;

class ImageController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function create(){
        return view('image.create');
    }

    public function save(Request $request){

        //Validacion
        $validate = $this->validate($request, [
            'description' => 'required',
            'image_path' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg'
        ]);

        //Recoger datos
        $image_path = $request->file('image_path');
        $description = $request->input('description');

        //Asignar valores al objeto
        $user = \Auth::user();
        $image = New Image();
        $image->user_id = $user->id; 
        $image->description = $description;

        //Subir fichero
        if($image_path){
            $image_path_name = time().$image_path->getClientOriginalName();
            Storage::disk('images')->put($image_path_name, File::get($image_path));
            $image->image_path = $image_path_name;
        }

        //Resize y Subir a la BD
        $image = Image::make($image_path->path())
                ->resize(400, 400)
                ->save($image_path_name );

        //Redirect
        return redirect()->route('home')->with([
            'message' => 'La imagen se a cargado correctamente'
        ]);
    }
```

Si dejo de utilizar el App\Image eso hace que dejen de funcionar ciertas partes de codigo que tengo en el mismo controlador.

Comment: Lo que interpreto es que yo estoy pasando una variable cuando se espera un array, pero no se como hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

De tu código podría inferirse que tienes un modelo `Image` que estás manejando con eloquent. En caso afirmativo, cuando crees que estás usando el facade Image de intervention, en realidad es otra entidad.

Sacando ese factor y suponiendo que solamente existen el request y el facade Image, cuando haces:

```
$image_path = $request->file('image_path');
```

`$image_path` no es un string con la ruta a un archivo. Es un objeto de tipo
`Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile`.

Por su parte, Intervention espera un string en el método `make` ([ref: documentación](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel))

```
$image = Image::make('public/foo.jpg')->resize(300, 200);
```

Así que podrías generar la imagen redimensionada como:

```
$image_path_name = time().$image_path->getClientOriginalName();

$image = Image::make($image_path->path())
                ->resize(400, 400)
                ->save($image_path_name );
```

Es posible que el error venga de antes. Como ya te dije estás usando dos veces `Image` y me late que esperas que hagan cosas distintas.